# Show ToolTip in ListView using JqueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How show ToolTip in ListView  using JqueryMobile

when you hover over image(icon)

[image]

Comment: Mobile jquery was meant for mobile devices hence tooltip is less relevant However alternatively you can look for this workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198756/touch-friendly-tooltip

Comment: Did you try adding a title attribute to each icon?